# I want to display a blurred image in imageJ. Why doesn't this work?

Tags: java, imagej

I'm very very new to imageJ but know a little Java.

Essentially I want to open a file from an OpenDialog display the image, then blur the image and display the resulting blurred image. My program compiles, however the two images look the same. Can anybody help? How do I make the program display a blurred and unblurred image?

```
import ij.*;
import ij.io.*;
import ij.process.*;
import ij.gui.*;
import java.awt.*;
import ij.plugin.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;


public class opens_ implements PlugIn {

    ImagePlus imp;

    public void run(String arg){
    OpenDialog od = new OpenDialog("Open.....", arg);
    Opener op = new Opener();
    String directory = od.getDirectory();
    String filename = od.getFileName();
    if (filename==null) return ;
    imp =  op.openImage(directory, filename);
    imp.show(); 

    ImageProcessor improc = imp.getProcessor();
    improc.smooth();

    ImagePlus alter = new ImagePlus("alter", improc) ;
    alter.show();


    }

}
```

Thanks

Bateman

Comment: Both images are displayed and neither are blurred.

Answer (score 4):

When you call `.smooth()` on `improc`, that call alters the image data contained by the `ImageProcessor`, which is being displayed by the original `ImagePlus`.  Then you create a new `ImagePlus` based on the same `ImageProcessor`, so of course it's the blurred image rather than the original.  If you don't want the original to be altered, then you can duplicate the `ImageProcessor` before smoothing, for example by changing the line:

```
ImageProcessor improc = imp.getProcessor();
```

... to:

```
ImageProcessor improc = imp.getProcessor().duplicate();
```

---

*Update:* when I tested your code, I saw both images as blurred.  If you still see the original images, try adding the following to the end of your run method:

```
imp.updateAndDraw()
alter.updateAndDraw()
```

Comment: Both images are displayed and neither are blurred.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that updateAndDraw() is also supposed to display the images, however when I remove imp.show() from the above code and add imp.updateAndDraw() and alter.updateAndDraw(), the program compiles but displays no images. Any further advice? Thank you for your time.

Comment: You need `.show()` to make sure that the `ImagePlus` window is displayed at all, rather than hidden.  The `.updateAndDraw()` call just tells the `ImagePlus` to redraw from the pixel data, and won't have any effect if you haven't displayed the window with `.show()`